# How to get hash value using key on spring data redis?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

On redis I have added key S000, and I want load hash object with that key.
I always get NULL from even I passed the correct key.
How can I do that, please find screenshot below for more detail.
Thank!

[image]

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName("localhost");
        configuration.setPort(9000);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, User> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, User> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    @Autowire
    private final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    public Object fetchUserById(String key) {
        return  redisTemplate.opsForHash().entries(key);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using port 9000 in your code. Note: in your image, port is 6379.

Comment: Yes, but I expose docker port to 9000
I can connect to redis server and save caches as usual.
Unfortunately  I can not get those hash

Comment: One more thing, if I create user by above service
then I can get response back by userId or username but redis commander will not working. It show refreshing til timeout, and next time login to that UI I can't do anything. Hello brother @sazzad did u ever meet this issue.

thank you!

Comment: No, I didn't meet this issue.

Comment: Now, I fixed it by using StringRedisTemplate